# Get list of distinct values in one column with common value in one column

Tags: mysql

I have a table of product numbers and account numbers in a database. I'd like to create a list of which accounts bought each product. See sample below.

```
table purchases<br>
|product_id|account_id|
|1|8|
|2|7|
|2|8|
|3|8|
|3|9|
```

Desired query output:

```
|product_id|accounts|
|1|8|
|2|8,7|
|3|8,9|
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`group_concat`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) should do the trick:

```
SELECT   product_id, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT account_id) AS accounts
FROM     purchases
GROUP BY product_id
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Demo here:**

## Rextester